# SQL Query to retrive Data as Column1 associated with Column 2

Tags: java, sql, associations

I stuckup with a sql query where column1 and column2 are associated in way their pair should be unique.

```
    Sample Database: 

     ID                 Version                Desc                update Date
     ---               --------                --------            -------
     1234                 1                     xoyz                  10/12/2014
     1234                 2                     ixyz                  10/12/2014
     1235                 1                     iuiu                  10/12/2014
     1235                 2                     popo                  10/12/2014
     1234                 3                     xypz                  10/12/2014
     1235                 3                     xyiz                  10/12/2014
     1236                 1                     xyzu                  10/12/2014
     1235                 4                     xyzr                  10/12/2014
     1236                 2                     xyze                  10/12/2014
     1235                 5                     xyrz                  10/12/2014
```

I need a query to retrieve records from the table as follows..

```
   ID             Version                    Desc            UpdatedDate

   1234                 3                     xypz                  10/12/2014
   1235                 5                     xyrz                  10/12/2014
   1236                 2                     xyze                  10/12/2014
```

In simple words..
1. ID , version are integer. Desc, Date are Strings
2. In result (ID,Version) is unique.

I need records as..., ID and It's associate Max Version with DESC and UPDATE DATE

```
  Thanks.
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: I am using DB2 Database.. I am not sure SQL version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
Select  T.ID, T.Version, T.[Desc], T.[Update Date]
From    Table T
Join
(
    Select      ID, Max(Version) CurVersion
    From        Table
    Group By    ID
) X On X.ID = T.ID And X.CurVersion = T.Version
Order By T.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an aggregate query. I don't know exactly what database you're running, but the query will look something like this:

```
SELECT my_table.'ID', my_table.Version, my_table.'Desc', my_table.UpdatedDate
FROM my_table INNER JOIN
(SELECT 'ID', MAX(Version)
 FROM my_table
 GROUP BY 'ID') AS max_version ON 
   my_table.ID = max_version.ID and my_table.Version = max_version.Version
```

There are other ways of doing this, but this should get you started.

Be careful, 2 of the columns you listed are likely reserved words and likely need special escaping of some sort: `ID` and `Desc`